Why does Mathematica consider (0, 0, 0) as an eigenvector?
For the matrix
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Mathematica returns the following as a triple of eigenvectors: $(0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)$.
Why does Mathematica consider the zero vector as an eigenvector?
I just used this simple code:
Eigenvectors[{{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]

which returns
{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} 

(Sorry, I wrote the wrong Matrix, I edited.)

5th bullet point under "Details" of documentation: "For an n[Cross]n matrix, Eigenvectors always returns a list of length n. The list contains each of the independent eigenvectors of the matrix, supplemented if necessary with an appropriate number of vectors of zeros. »"

@MichaelE2 I really admire you guys for reading the Documentation :/

Presence of {0,0,0} in the result of Eigenvectors[] simply means the matrix is NOT diagonalizable.

In fact, the documentation for Eignvectors has already addressed this question.

For an n×n matrix, Eigenvectors always returns a list of length n. The list contains each of the independent eigenvectors of the matrix, supplemented if necessary with an appropriate number of vectors of zeros.


Let us look in the documentation (Details and Options) to Eigenvectors

For an nxn matrix, Eigenvectors always returns a list of length n. The list contains each of the independent eigenvectors of the matrix, supplemented if necessary with an appropriate number of vectors of zeros.

